# NodeJS - page is reloaded in express after post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm using NodeJS and MongoDB. I'm connected to MongoDb via Mongoose.

What I currently want to do is, to show filtered results.

**The problem I actually have is that the /main page seems to get called after the filtering, because I get all results displayed and the results do not match my console output (so do not match the filtered results). 
I don't know why. Normally renderResults should only render the main page once after the filtering.**

```
    var auth = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.session && req.session.user) {
        return next();
    } else {
        res.status(401);
        return res.render("pages/noaccess");
    }
};
```

**The base contextroot the problem is about, is that:**

```
app.get('/main', auth, function(req, res) {
    getItems(req, res, function(results) {
        renderResults(req, res, results);
    });
});

function renderResults(req, res, results) {
    res.render('pages/main', {
        offerings: results.items,
        ownUser: {
            id: req.session.user || ""
        },
        filterObj: {
            isActivated: typeof results.filterObj !== 'undefined',
            filterFor: typeof results.filterObj !== 'undefined' ? results.filterObj.filter : "",
            filterText: typeof results.filterObj !== 'undefined' ? results.filterObj.filterText : ""
        }
    });
}
```

What I've written to provide filtering is that:

```
app.post('/filterItems', auth, function(req, res) {
console.log("Filterrequest received.");
    getItems(req, res, function(results) {
        renderResults(req, res, results);
    });
});


 function getItems(req, res, callback) {
    connectToDB(function() {
        retrieveItems(req, res, function(result) {
            console.log(result.items);
            console.log("offerings retrieved");
            if (callback && isFunction(callback)) {
                callback(result);
            }
        });
    });
}

var connectToDB = function(callback) {
        var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/Test';

        if (!dbconnected) {
            console.log("No Databaseconnection existing. Going to create one...");
            MongoClient.connect(url, {
                useMongoClient: true
            });
            database = MongoClient.connection;
            database.on('connected', function() {
                dbconnected = true;
                console.log("Successfully Connected to database.");

                if (callback && isFunction(callback)) {
                    callback(database);
                }
            });
        } else {
            if (callback && isFunction(callback)) {
                callback(database);
            }
        }
    },
    retrieveItems = function(req, res, callback) {
        var baseCond = req && req.query,
            tOfferType = (baseCond && req.query.type && ("wanted" === req.query.type.toLowerCase())) ? "wanted" : "offerings",
            filter =  req.body && req.body['filter'] && req.body['filterText'] ? {
                filter: req.body['filter'],
                filterText: req.body['filterText']
            } : undefined,
            isFullTextSearch = filter && ("nofilter" === filter.filter || "All" === filter.filter || !filter.filter.length);

        console.log("offertype variable:" + tOfferType);
        if(filter) {
          console.log("!!! Filtervalue: " + filter.filter);
        } else {
          console.log("!!! No filtervalue received!");
        }


        if (filter && filter.filter && filter.filter.length && filter.filterText && filter.filterText.length) {
            console.log("Using fulltextsearch now..");
            console.log("Fulltextsearch activated? " + isFullTextSearch);
            doFilterRetrieve(tOfferType, filter, isFullTextSearch, function(retrievedFilteredResults) {
                if (callback && isFunction(callback)) {
                    callback({
                        items: retrievedFilteredResults,
                        offertype: tOfferType,
                        filterObj: filter
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log("Using normal retrieve now..");
            database.collection(tOfferType).find({}).toArray(function(err, results) {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (callback && isFunction(callback)) {
                    callback({
                        items: results,
                        offertype: tOfferType,
                        filterObj: filter
                    });
                }
            });
        }


    }
```

After login (that seems to be pretty fine):

```
User is logged in: Yes
    redirect to /main
    No Databaseconnection existing. Going to create one...
    Successfully Connected to database.
    offertype variable:offerings
    !!! No filtervalue received!
    Using normal retrieve now..
    offerings retrieved
    [ { _id: 5a0469ca487f333bb4c16e6b,
        start:
         { city: 'Aachen',
           zipcode: '37464',
           datetime: '2017-11-11T07:00',
           street: 'Salaweg 2' },
        destination:
         { city: 'Köln',
           zipcode: '51105',
           datetime: '2017-11-12T07:00',
           street: 'Westerwaldstraße 92' },
        baseData:
         { isOffer: true,
           name: 'Jenny Baldau',
           email: 'skrur@web.de',
           mobilenumber: '0183474875',
           description: 'gtgt',
           costs: '2,00',
           freeplacesamount: '3',
           personID: 'fiz_baldau42',
           created: 2017-11-09T14:44:26.915Z } },
      { _id: 5a046ab057d3a61d8c23eafb,
        start:
         { city: 'München',
           zipcode: '02837',
           datetime: '2017-11-11T07:00',
           street: 'Menchweg 23' },
        destination:
         { city: 'Köln',
           zipcode: '51105',
           datetime: '2017-11-12T07:00',
           street: 'Westerwaldstraße 92' },
        baseData:
         { isOffer: true,
           name: 'Daniel Ebert',
           email: 'daniel.ebert@web.de',
           mobilenumber: '017354536374',
           description: 'Ich biete eine Mitfahrgelegenheit aus München',
           costs: '2,00',
           freeplacesamount: '3',
           personID: 'fia51ebert',
           created: 2017-11-09T14:44:26.915Z } } ]
```

After submit of the fulltext search. Searchterm was "Jenny":

```
 Filterrequest received.
    offertype variable:offerings
    !!! Filtervalue: All
    Using fulltextsearch now..
    Fulltextsearch activated? true
    doFilterRetrieve mit Fulltextsuche...
    fulltextsuche nach :Jenny
    Zeige ergebnisse aus Volltextsuche:
    [ { _id: 5a0469ca487f333bb4c16e6b,
        start:
         { city: 'Aachen',
           zipcode: '37464',
           datetime: '2017-11-11T07:00',
           street: 'Salaweg 2' },
        destination:
         { city: 'Köln',
           zipcode: '51105',
           datetime: '2017-11-12T07:00',
           street: 'Westerwaldstraße 92' },
        baseData:
         { isOffer: true,
           name: 'Jenny Baldau',
           email: 'skrur@web.de',
           mobilenumber: '0183474875',
           description: 'gtgt',
           costs: '2,00',
           freeplacesamount: '3',
           personID: 'fiz_baldau42',
           created: 2017-11-09T14:44:26.915Z } } ]
    offerings retrieved
    [ { _id: 5a0469ca487f333bb4c16e6b,
        start:
         { city: 'Aachen',
           zipcode: '37464',
           datetime: '2017-11-11T07:00',
           street: 'Salaweg 2' },
        destination:
         { city: 'Köln',
           zipcode: '51105',
           datetime: '2017-11-12T07:00',
           street: 'Westerwaldstraße 92' },
        baseData:
         { isOffer: true,
           name: 'Jenny Baldau',
           email: 'skrur@web.de',
           mobilenumber: '0183474875',
           description: 'gtgt',
           costs: '2,00',
           freeplacesamount: '3',
           personID: 'fiz_baldau42',
           created: 2017-11-09T14:44:26.915Z } } ]
    offertype variable:offerings
    !!! No filtervalue received!
    Using normal retrieve now..
    offerings retrieved
    [ { _id: 5a0469ca487f333bb4c16e6b,
        start:
         { city: 'Aachen',
           zipcode: '37464',
           datetime: '2017-11-11T07:00',
           street: 'Salaweg 2' },
        destination:
         { city: 'Köln',
           zipcode: '51105',
           datetime: '2017-11-12T07:00',
           street: 'Westerwaldstraße 92' },
        baseData:
         { isOffer: true,
           name: 'Jenny Baldau',
           email: 'skrur@web.de',
           mobilenumber: '0183474875',
           description: 'gtgt',
           costs: '2,00',
           freeplacesamount: '3',
           personID: 'fiz_baldau42',
           created: 2017-11-09T14:44:26.915Z } },
      { _id: 5a046ab057d3a61d8c23eafb,
        start:
         { city: 'München',
           zipcode: '02837',
           datetime: '2017-11-11T07:00',
           street: 'Menchweg 23' },
        destination:
         { city: 'Köln',
           zipcode: '51105',
           datetime: '2017-11-12T07:00',
           street: 'Westerwaldstraße 92' },
        baseData:
         { isOffer: true,
           name: 'Daniel Ebert',
           email: 'daniel.ebert@web.de',
           mobilenumber: '017354536374',
           description: 'Ich biete eine Mitfahrgelegenheit aus München',
           costs: '2,00',
           freeplacesamount: '3',
           personID: 'fia51ebert',
           created: 2017-11-09T14:44:26.915Z } } ]
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Can we see the renderResults function ?

Comment: @Liberateur oh yeah, sorry. I added it. Thanks for the hint

Comment: You correct too quickly your post ha ha ha

Comment: Can you show all your logs ? And can you place one more line `console.log(result)` just after `retrieveItems(req, res, function(result) {` in getItems function

Comment: @Liberateur that would be console.log(result.items) then. Yes, I added it, please see my log above.

Comment: Ok thanks ! Can you display the contents of the view pages/main ?

Comment: @Liberateur what do you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158697/discussion-between-sirisch-and-liberateur).